# Marshalling an integer pointer inside a structure as a callback

Tags: c#, .net, c, callback, marshalling

I have a C structure used for callback that I need to marshall to C# .NET:

```
struct CTMDeviceInfo {
    enum CTMDeviceType eDeviceType;
    char *             szDeviceModel;
    char *             szDeviceSubModel;
    int32_t *          piDeviceID;
};
```

This is my C# version:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct CTMDeviceInfo
{
    public CTMDeviceType deviceType;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string deviceModel;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string deviceSubModel;

    public IntPtr deviceId;
};
```

Which is used inside another structure:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct CTMDeviceError
{
    public CTMDeviceInfo deviceInfo;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public Int32 resultCode;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public Int32 extendedResultCode;

    public IntPtr denomination;

    public IntPtr changeDue;
};
```

My problem is that the "IntPtr deviceId" does not consistently return the correct value every time a callback was made.

I was expecting an integer value of 5, 15 or 16 but it keeps returning random values like 106, 865412, 652272, etc.

I don't know what I did wrong. What I did though is to prevent the callback in my managed code to be garbage collected using GCHandle.

Here is the sequence on how I did it:

From my unmanaged code I have this CDECL callback method:

```
void ctm_add_device_error_event_handler(CTMDeviceErrorCallback);

typedef void (CTMDeviceErrorCallback) (struct CTMEventInfo, struct CTMDeviceError );
```

This is my managed code:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate void OnDeviceErrorCallBack(CTMEventInfo evtInfo, CTMDeviceError deviceError);

[DllImport("libctmclient-0.dll", EntryPoint = "ctm_add_device_error_event_handler", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void AddDeviceErrorEventHandler([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] OnDeviceErrorCallBack deviceErrorCallBack);

OnDeviceErrorCallBack deviceErrorCallback;
GCHandle deviceErrorCallbackGCHandle;

deviceErrorCallback = new OnDeviceErrorCallBack(OnDeviceError);
deviceErrorCallbackGCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(deviceErrorCallback);
AddDeviceErrorEventHandler(deviceErrorCallback);
```

And this is where the callback is handled:

```
public void OnDeviceError(CTMEventInfo evtInfo, CTMDeviceError deviceError)
{
    int nDeviceId = Marshal.ReadInt32(deviceError.deviceInfo.deviceId);
}
```

I tried to use unsafe to use pointers directly but the issue is still the same.

```
public unsafe int *deviceId; //instead of IntPtr

int nDeviceId = 0;

unsafe
{    
    nDeviceId = *(deviceError.deviceInfo.deviceId);
}
```

I'm sure that my unmanaged code returned the correct value because I have logs but when it reached in my managed code, somehow another value was returned.
It's like it is reading on a different reference or something.

Hope somewhat could help me because I am stuck for a while now.
Thanks!

Comment: Rarely `Pack = 1` is used C-side... If there is no equivalent `#pragma pack(1)` C-side, then don't put it. And if possible, C-side do a `sizeof(CTMDeviceType)` to be sure it is of the same size as the C# counterpart.

Comment: And try to see if the other fields are marshaled correctly...

Comment: Di you mean just remove the "Pack = 1" statement?
I tried it in both of the structures but still no luck.
The other fields works because they always returned the correct value.
I am not permitted to modify the C-side which is sad.

Comment: Yes try to remove it

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: Is the sizeof(CTMDeviceType) == 4 in C? What is sizeof(CTMDeviceInfo) and sizeof(CTMDeviceError) in C?

Comment: `public IntPtr deviceId;` will be converted to a char* in C not int*. So I would use a `BitConverter` to make the returned char* from C, an int array in c#

Comment: CTMDeviceType is an enum to either 5, 15, 16 and 17 so I guess the size is 2?
I don't know the size of CTMDeviceInfo or CTMDeviceError structures but the value returned by IntPtr deviceId is an integer to either 5, 15 and 16 so I guess it's size is also 2?

Comment: @aljochimera The problem here is that if you don't know the sizeof() of the C struct, then it is difficult to comprehend if you are marshaling it correctly.

Comment: @xanatos Do you mean that I need to get the size in C and return it as an added field inside the structure?

Comment: @aljochimera No, you need to write 10 C lines to see what is the sizeof of EVERYTHING, write it on paper, remove the 10 C lines.

Comment: @Md.SumsuddinShojib I tried your advise but I don't know if I did it right. It didn't work though.

    int val = (int)deviceError.deviceInfo.deviceId;
    byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(val);

    if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
        Array.Reverse(bytes);

    int i = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);

Comment: @xanatos I will try it and will update you on the results

Answer (score 0):

Use following c# structure.  You can get the two string from the pointer later in the code. :

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct CTMDeviceInfo
{
    public CTMDeviceType deviceType;

    public IntPtr deviceModel;

    public IntPtr deviceSubModel;

    public IntPtr deviceId;
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is still the same.

Comment: Are you still using following which doesn't return back the value you are looking for : public void OnDeviceError(CTMEventInfo evtInfo, CTMDeviceError deviceError)
{
    int nDeviceId = Marshal.ReadInt32(deviceError.deviceInfo.deviceId);
}

Comment: yes. i also tried using pointers directly using unsafe as shown above but it is still the same

Comment: What is the value of nDeviceID?  The method doesn't return this value.

Comment: i was expecting only an integer value of 15 but it keeps on returning random values like 106, 86, 15, 106, 86, 15.. etc. The sequence keeps repeating so I don't always get 15.

Comment: That doesn't seem like random data. What type of device?  If internet I would try debug with a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.